# Insert new record in EntityDataSource

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

How can i insert new record in EntityDataSource (from gridview)

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having the same problem right now and I found this:
[How to fire up insert event](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/d8a3ecd8-55dd-45ad-8175-d7ce912f46c2/)

Not what I hoped for but it seems to be working.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to add your own insert-functionality its easier to use a ListView instead of a GridView.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adodotnetentityframework/thread/a06bc929-08b6-44fd-87be-80075a9a7137